# Using Sharepoint UI is there a way of knowing what event receiver is installed against a library

Tags: event-receivers

Using Sharepoint UI is there a way of knowing what event receiver is installed against a library?

I have a event receiver that adds installed against document library and all it does is to set item level permission when a document is added. 
I'm documenting the customizations that have been done so far and wanted to know if there is a quick UI based way of determining if there are any event receiver registered against a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything in the standard SharePoint UI which can show event receivers.

But there are several codeplex project which might help you. If you don't mind it being a utility to run on the servers then [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) is a utility which will give you all the information you want about your SharePoint farm

Comment: Thanks @PJ. At the end created a webservice that does this.......
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists["My Documents"];

            Console.WriteLine(list.EventReceivers.Count + " found");
            foreach (SPEventReceiverDefinition listItem in list.EventReceivers)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(listItem.Class + "\nType: " + listItem.Type);
            }